# Spring Integration Doubts: CRUD operations and sharing events between components

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-integration, integration

I am currently developing a simple Spring web app using Spring integration framework. I have read about the enterprise integration patterns, purpose, benefits... I have get rid out of the ServiceLayer and delegated the app workflow to the integration framework. But I have come across some design issues where I am stuck and I would appreciate some light in terms of design. Here below I ll try to explain them, thanks in advance.

**1. CRUD operations with Spring Integration Framework**

Lets say you have 2 endpoints connected through a direct channel, 1 endpoint receives requests and the other one processes those requests. I don't want to talk from the implementation perspective but from the design (as I have stated before) but in order to clarify it out, image that you implement the receiving endpoint as a RestController connected to a Gateway and the other endpoint as an ServiceActivator connected to a DB adapter.
Now, there are 4 basic operations the user can request, Create, Read, Update and Delete (basic CRUD). Since the receiver endpoint can **only** execute one method (handleMessage method), what is the correct way to multiplex the 4 operations?

1. Adding some kind of tag to the message header? It seems ugly to me and besides the receiver endpoint will have to implement a block of if-else. It would be easier to just connect the controller to an interface and call the methods and get rid of spring integration.
2. Create 4 ServiceActivator connected to the same DB? I don't like it either, imagine if you had 30 operations instead of 4.
3. Any other solution I have not found yet? For example, send each operation through a different channel, so that you would have 4 channels. You can do this from the Gateway point of view but the problem is that the ServiceActivator can only have 1 inbound channel.

**2. Sharing events between endpoints with Spring Integration Framework**

Lets say you have a Gateway connected to a Transformer.The transformer inits a thread in which parses some data and send it to the next endpoint when finishes. 
Now, the Gateway client needs to know the status of the request it sent through the channel (since the Gateway knows nothing about the Transformer or its implementation they shouldn't share anything). How can be it accomplished since the transformer only has 1 inbound channel and 1 output channel and there is no way to publish results back through a third channel? In essence, the question is, how do you share event without coupling the endpoints or breaking the integration patterns architecture? 
P.D.:Please avoid no clean answers such as static shared objects, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M-m-m. Your concern somehow isn't clear.

When you had a ServiceLayer before, I'm pretty sure a lot of methods for particular operation didn't disturb you. So, not sure why you are so worry about message channel distinguishing for operations when you switched to Messaging architecture.

At the same time I guess that `@Cotroller` with `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE` etc `@RequestMapping` for its methods don't concern you again.

That is just a bit inconvenience to have extra objects in your application in face of `MessageChannel`s in between your endpoints. But at the same time it is a bonus when you start to think about your application as a bunch of message flows, where each of them is separated my the `MessageChannel` and you can modify any flow not affecting any other. Plus don't forget that with the `MessageChannel` you simply can go to the distributed mode, when your business logic is the same, but messages are travel over the network for target services or other purposes.

So, IMO I's have `@MessagingGateway` to call from the `@Controller` and each gateway's method would be mapped to particular `MessageChannel`.

Thanks to annotation model you could have only one target service, but with method for each CRUD operation marked with the `@ServiceActivator` for particular `MessageChannel`:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface CrudGateway {

   @Gateway(requestChannel = "getChannel")
   Object get(Object id);

   @Gateway(requestChannel = "saveChannel")
   Object save(Object object);

   @Gateway(requestChannel = "deleteChannel")
   boolean delete(Object object);

}

...

@Service
public class CrudService {

   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "getChannel")
   public Object get(Object id) {
       // SELECT
   }

   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "saveChannel")
   public Object save(Object object) {
       // INSERT or UPDATE
   }

   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "deleteChannel")
   public boolean delete(Object object) {
       // DELETE
   }

}
```

For your second question there is some answer as well.

Consider to use `PublishSubscribeChannel` as an output of that `transformer`.

On the other hand there is `RecipientListRouter` to distribute incoming message to several recipients - channels, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much Artem, very useful answer. I understood the first part but didn't get the second one.
From what I understand, the transformer can only have one method, so it is impossible to post a message notifying the state of the thread which is running inside the transformer via publish/subscribe.
To sum up I got a controller -> gateway -> transformer -> outbound adapter. There is a task inside the transformer. I need to poll the task percentage from the controller in order to show it in the html view. How could be accomplish? My other issue is the scope of that thread. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can publish percentage from that thread to some `QueueChannel` and when your controller will come to check the state, it will just poll messages from that `QueueChannel`. Or... You can simply use `AtomicReference` to place the latest progress and controller will just take a look for that value to the `AtomicReference.get()`.

Comment: Thank you again Artem. I didn't know you can inject channels directly on classes. I thought it was all automated with annotations and that you have no control over channel object. Am i breaking the architecture if a transformer publish other kind of messages as it would have more than one responsibility (transformation)?Besides, if there is a task in the transformer per controller session, how can I discriminate that task? furthermore, how can I update via the channel to the correct session thread? Should I use message headers or maybe @Session when creating the channels/endpoints/task?thank u